# ¿Dónde está el botón de Ayuda para usuarios en Spanish.SE?

Tags: soporte, interfaz-de-usuario

No veo el botón para conseguir ayuda en el "top bar" de Spanish Language beta.  Me refiero al botón con signo de interrogación.

Antes creo que sí se veía.  ¿Es esto un efecto del nuevo "top bar"?  De ser así, ¿es posible reponerlo en el top bar?

Answer (score 4):

¡Está algo escondida!

[image]

Si te fijas, está en la esquina derecha, donde dice:

```
help    chat    log out
^^^^
```

---

Nótese, sin embargo, que esto ocurre solamente si tienes cierta reputación. Los visitantes no registrados o usuarios sin [acceso a las colas de revisión](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues) sí ven el icono:

[image]

Con el acceso a estas colas nos referimos a pore acceder a `/review`, cuyo umbral cambia [según el estado del sitio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160292/209901):

- 350 puntos de reputación en sitios en beta
- 500 puntos de reputación en sitios graduados

Todo esto [lo explicó](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343165/new-top-bar-wheres-the-help-menu-gone/343184#comment444046_343165) un desarrollador de Stack Exchange:

> we keep help icon for users who don't have access to /review yet. once you get access to /review we just replace help icon with review. "high-rep" vs "low-rep" was our internal naming convention for those two cases. nevertheless, for "high-rep" users Help Center is still accessible from footer. (this is actually area where most of websites put "help" link so it's quite common pattern. and yes, i know there are other sites too :)) – Paweł♦

Comment: Gracias.  Me parece que se necesita ayuda para encontrar ayuda.  Me parece que esto es demasiado difícil para los principiantes.

Comment: @WalterMitty edité la respuesta. Fíjate que la gente no registrada sí lo ve. Y los usuarios con poca reputación, pero no sé cuánta.

Comment: Pienso que necesitas 500 para eliminar help

Comment: Gracias. no lo sabía.  Solo sé lo que veo en mi cuenta.

Comment: @mdewey me basé en [¿Cómo vamos a pretender que un usuario nuevo lea la ayuda si quedó escondida en la nueva barra?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2128/83), donde mencionan que el límite lo marca el acceso a las colas de revisión. En sitios graduados ese límite está en 500 puntos, pero en los beta como Spanish.SE está en 350.

Comment: Yes, I was looking at one of the meta sites which obviously was not referring to beta sites.

Comment: @mdewey acabo de confirmarlo [con la ayuda de Mariano](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2128/83). Efectivamente, cuando puedes acceder a `/review` ya no te sale el icono.

Comment: Yo tengo tanto la ayuda como el acceso a la revisión.